# How to change the default useragent in safari in windows7?

Tags: windows, browser, safari, default, user-agent

I want to change the default useragent of my safari browser in Windows7 OS.

Whenever I change from Develop-->UserAgent--> other & restart it, it will set to default.
I want to override the default.

can you please tell me hoe can I do that?

Comment: I disagree that this is off topic.  I was seeking this information to assist me in using Safari as an iPad browser simulator on Windows.  That seems to me to be a very dev related topic.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the User Agent Preference is not remembered on restarts.  It's only available for the current session.

Why do you need to remember the preference?  You can always check what the browser agent is returning by checking here

[Check your user agent string](http://www.myuseragentstring.com/)